# Adding multiple VoiceGrants in AccessToken object in Twilio node library

Tags: android, ios, twilio, twilio-api

I am getting an error like this in Twilio Voice Call:

> Type of credential provided in access token does not match that of the registration. For example, you included the SID of an APS type
>   Credential in the access token for an Android application using GCM.

I already completed the setup for android, ios and node server side.

I have a question to resolve this issue.

Can I pass multiple VoiceGrant objects in AccessToken object like below at the server side:

```
const voiceGrant1 = new VoiceGrant({
  outgoingApplicationSid: outgoingApplicationSid,
  pushCredentialSid: pushCredSidObject['ios']['prod']  // iOS platform PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID
});

const voiceGrant2 = new VoiceGrant({
  outgoingApplicationSid: outgoingApplicationSid,
  pushCredentialSid: pushCredSidObject['android']['prod']  // android platform PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID
});

const token = new AccessToken(accountSid, apiKey, apiSecret);
token.addGrant(voiceGrant1);
token.addGrant(voiceGrant2);
```

Is it valid to add grant multiple times? If not, please provide me another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think possible solution could be when we request for token from application, we can pass extra params, so let's say for iOS you pass `platform=iOS` and for android you pass `platform=android`

Now when your node code get executed you can get those extra param by `event.platform` something like this just like you try to get identity and based on platform value you can add Grant as per needed.

Hope this helps :)